# Why Collection's toArray() method does not convert nested objects to arrays when called in a PHPUnit test?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, phpunit, laravel-valet

#### Expected behavior:

[Collections toArray()](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#method-toarray) method should convert a collection to a plain `array` and all of the collection's nested objects that are an instance of `Arrayable` to an array.

#### Actual behavior:

`toArray()` method converts a collection to a plain `array` but the nested objects are not converted.
Note that this behavior observed only when `toArray()` called via PHPUnit. When `toArray()` function called within an app or via Laravel Tinker it works as expected.

#### Steps To Reproduce:

[Repository with a failing test](https://github.com/nikkiselev/laravel-phpunit-to-array-bug)
[Test](https://github.com/nikkiselev/laravel-phpunit-to-array-bug/blob/master/tests/Unit/CollectionToArrayTest.php)

Clone, install packages, run PHPUnit.

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Unit;

use App\User;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Arrayable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;
use Tests\TestCase;

class CollectionToArrayTest extends TestCase
{
    use RefreshDatabase;

    /** @test */
    public function it_converts_nested_objects_that_are_an_instance_of_arrayable_to_an_array()
    {
        factory(User::class)->create();

        $users = User::get();

        // passed
        $this->assertInstanceOf(Arrayable::class, $users[0]);

        // Failed asserting that App\User Object is of type "array"
        $this->assertIsArray($users->toArray()[0]);

        // passed
        $this->assertIsArray($users->toArray()[0]->toArray());
    }
}
```

Observations:

1. It've worked before, probably with previous versions of PHP and PHPUnit, however I couldn't identify the moment it has stopped.
2. It seems that [EnumeratesValues::toArray()](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/eca35179ed82a32ba90532ae21a08178581a461b/src/Illuminate/Support/Traits/EnumeratesValues.php#L716) is not called when `->toArray()` is called on Collection in the provided PHPUnit test.

Laravel Version: 7.0.7
PHP Version: 7.3.15
PHPUnit Version: 8.5.2

Comment: This should work, what class does User inherits from?

Comment: @mrhn, default `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User`. It's a fresh install and any `Collection` shows the described behavior

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved the issue.

I have Laravel Valet and PHPUnit installed globally. Valet requires `tightenco/collect` package that is in a conflict with Laravel Collections.

When running PHPUnit, `\Illuminate\Support\Collection` gets replaced with `Tightenco\Collect\Support\Collection` that works differently.

So, I've removed global PHPUnit and used local version instead.

I created a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/31841)